# Angular ContentChildren get directive Inputs and TemplateRef

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I am trying to get `TemplateRef` for `ng-template` and `input` parameters.
app.component.html:

```
<my-parent>
    <ng-template my-directive title="Title1" let-dataItem="dataItem">
        <div>{{dataItem|json}}</div>
    </ng-template>
</my-parent>
```

Problem is I can get only `TemplateRef` (title is undefined):
my-parent.html:

```
<div *ngFor="let detail of details" [title]="detail.title"> //!!! detail.title is undefined
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="detail;context:{dataItem: dataItem}"></ng-container>
</div>
```

my-parent.ts

```
@ContentChildren(MyDirective, { read: TemplateRef }) details: QueryList<MyDirective>;
```

Or I can get Input parameters:
my-parent.ts

```
@ContentChildren(MyDirective) details: QueryList<MyDirective>;   

//in html detail.title is defined, but detail is not template and I get exception in line 
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="detail;context:{dataItem: dataItem}"></ng-container>
```

Exception:

```
TypeError: templateRef.createEmbeddedView is not a function
```

I think I need this version of ContentChildren:

```
@ContentChildren(MyDirective, { read: TemplateRef }) details: QueryList<MyDirective>;
```

but how can I get `MyDirective` input parameter (`title` in this case)?

I know I can use both:

```
@ContentChildren(MyDirective, { read: TemplateRef }) detailsRefs: QueryList<MyDirective>;
@ContentChildren(MyDirective) detailsInputs: QueryList<MyDirective>;
```

And then merge it into new array:

```
public ngAfterViewInit(): void
{
  const refs = this.detailsRefs.toArray();
  const inputs = this.detailsInputs.toArray();
  for (let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++)
    this.details.push({templateRef: refs[i], inputs: inputs[i]});
}
```

But sure there is a better way.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It can be done by using DI:

```typescript
@Directive({
  selector: '[my-directive]'
})
export class MyDirective  {
  @Input() title: string;

  constructor(public templateRef: TemplateRef<any>) {}
}
```

now it should be easy to undestand that we can leverage the preceding directive like:

**parent.component.ts**

```typescript
@ContentChildren(MyDirective) details: QueryList<MyDirective>;
```

**parent.component.html**

```typescript
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="detail.templateRef
                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

**[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7qu5bn?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)**

Comment: this works but you need to add * in front of the directive selector. For example, if I use the selector `[myDirective]` on a `div` I will have to do `<div *myDirective></div>`

Comment: this saved my day!

Answer (score 2):

You can read `title` with an input in `my-directive` and then read it from there, for that you need to remove `{read: TemplateRef}`:

```
@ContentChildren(MyDirective) details: QueryList<MyDirective>;
...
detail.title
```

As far as I remember for structural directives the input needs to be prefixed with the selector.

```
@Directive({ selector: 'myDirective', ...})
class MyDirective {
  @Input() myDirectiveTitle:string;
}
```

and use it like

```
 <ng-template myDirective title="Title1" let-dataItem="dataItem">
```

and read the title using

```
detail.myDirectiveTitle
```

See also https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives

This code

```
@ContentChildren(MyDirective, { read: TemplateRef }) details: QueryList<MyDirective>;
```

should cause an error because when you read `TemplateRef`, `detail` should be of type `QueryList<TemplateRef>`.

Comment: Can you provide more concrete information than "doesn't work"? Ideally a http://stackblitz.com to reproduce and investigate.

Comment: I manage to do it. [Here is the awesome tool Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ndc9y7).

Comment: Not sure what the question is. As mentioned I don't think it is supposed to work. You can't get the title from the `TemplateRef`, only from the directive.

Comment: Perhaps using `{{details.toArray()[i].title}}` in the `Doesn't work:` part is what you want https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dyeper?file=app%2Fparent.component.html all the other changes I made shouldn't be necessary and were only for debugging purposes.